# Using content with the before psuedo selector to force new line

Tags: css

Normally something like this will force the `.free-entry` element onto a new line...

```
.free-entry:before {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

But I've run into a case where I can't get it to work.

I have an unordered list and within each `li` there is a `.free-entry` element. I'm trying to force the `.free-entry` element onto a new line but with no luck...

```
li .free-entry:before {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Normally `display:block` would work just fine, but `li` is `display:table-row` so block doesn't work.

```
li {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/1dy0a41w/) for more clarity.

Comment: See [CSS to line break before/after a particular `inline-block` item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609279/css-to-line-break-before-after-a-particular-inline-block-item) and [To What Self-Closing Elements Can ::before and ::after Pseudo-Elements be Applied](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26633229/1529630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work is that .free-entry is an `input` element.

Pseudo elements are not supported on replaced elements of which `input` is one.

Hence `.free-entry:before {...}` does nothing.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field) for more details

As a workaround to this you could place an :after pseudo element on the label like so:

```
label:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/1dy0a41w/4/)**

```css
li {
  display: table-row;
}
label:after {
  content: '\A';
 white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Other" name="choosemanytest_other[5]" checked="" />
    <label>Other</label>
    <input type="text" class="free-entry" value="A Tiger" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think what I'll do is wrap the `input` with a `span`. Thank you for your explanation. I searched but couldn't come up with anything substantial like your answer, probably because I didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I think you can solve it by changing the free-entry to a display: block

```
li .free-entry {
        display: block;
}
```