# :before and :after to HR in Microsoft Edge and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, pseudo-element

I'm puzzled in getting an icon `◆` to display around an `<hr>` tag in IE and Edge. I created a class to apply to apply to the hr, which displays fine in Firefox and Chrome, but I'm not sure how to get IE to behave.

How it should look: [Normal (Firefox and Chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ld19.jpg).

But in IE and Edge, the icons are hidden from view. I thought they weren't displaying at all, but when I added longer content to the `:before` and `:after` I could see that the content is hidden behind the `<hr>`, as part of the text was visible below the line.

I tried `overflow: visible` but it stays the same, and adding `padding` pushed the icons below the hr. Any help greatly appreciated!

CSS:

```
hr.fancy {
  border: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #E67E48;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

hr.fancy:after,
hr.fancy:before {
  content: '◆ test';
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #E67E48;
}

hr.fancy:before {
  float: left;
  right: 20px;
}

hr.fancy:after {
  float: right;
  left: 20px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1z4ykog/4/)

Comment: I am surprised it works at all in chrome & firefox... - :After and :Before are child pseudoelements... They need a parent - <br />, <hr /> are shortened elements without content, so child pseudoelements shouldn't be applied on them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i was wrong... It works with `<hr/>` element in IE, Edge

```css
hr.fancy {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #E67E48;
  clear: both;
  overflow:visible;
}

hr.fancy:after,
hr.fancy:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  color: #E67E48;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  content: '◆';
}

hr.fancy:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<hr class="fancy" />
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was also surprised it was possible but [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633229/to-what-self-closing-elements-can-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-be-applie) got me trying. Thanks for cleaning up what I'd done, it looks much better now.

Comment: @Crista you're welcome... your code worked (positioning was not solved the best way though) and for some reason only IE needed overflow visible to be explicitly defined.