# Custom checkbox with CSS ::before - not working in Firefox/Edge

Tags: html, css, checkbox, cross-browser, pseudo-element

I have come up against a very annoying CSS issue while trying to get a project working cross-browser (not bothered about IE, it's only a hobby project, but it would be nice to get it working on all modern browsers at the very least). It relates to some checkboxes which I wish to apply custom styles to - I know you can't do very much with the standard HTML `<input type="checkbox">` so I have done what is recommended in many places, and used a `::before` pseudo-element. And I was pleased with the result in Chrome. Imagine my surprise when I find that my custom checkbox simply doesn't display *at all* in Firefox!

I've been playing with this for a few hours and have stripped it right back to the very root of the problem - and it's something to do with the checkbox itself, rather than any other CSS it's interacting with. Here's the bare minimum example:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
    visibility: visible;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    color: #eddc23;
    border: 1px solid #eddc23;
    background-color: #540123;
    border-radius: 35%;
    line-height: 1.27;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
    content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

This should show a dark red checkbox which has a yellow tick when selected. It works perfectly on Chrome and Opera, but not at all on Firefox or Edge. (Here's a [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/robinzigmond/pen/NmeaeJ) of the same in case the Stack Overflow snippet somehow exhibits different behaviour). CSS isn't one of my strong points and despite a few hours of experimenting and googling, I'm baffled.

Would appreciate any pointers, not only as to how to get this working cross-browser, but as to *why* it's not working on FF/Edge (inspecting the element on Firefox shows no sign of a `::before` pseudo-element at all. I've also ruled out it being to do with the empty `content` property, since changing that to real text fails to make it visible in the browsers concerned).

Comment: I've had some enlightenment from my discussion with @NishargShah below, which led me via google to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633229/to-what-self-closing-elements-can-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-be-applie). Basically it seems browsers can do what they like with `::before` and `::after` for self-closing elements such as `<input>` - which of course explains the varying cross-browser results. I'm still interested in a "good" solution which doesn't involve a non-labelling `<label>`, if anyone can suggest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes with labels you can solve this type of problems

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

span {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  color: #eddc23;
  border: 1px solid #eddc23;
  background-color: #540123;
  border-radius: 35%;
  line-height: 1.27;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span::before {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you - that does indeed appear to be working on all browsers. Sadly it's far from ideal, since in reality I have a variety of different dyamically-generated checkboxes, so giving them ids will be problematic. And I don't like this totally non-semantic use of the `<label>` element. But it does work, and I should be able to adapt it somehow, so thank you :-)  Do you know why this is working on FF/Edge while the original version with just the pseudo-element was not?

Comment: The problem is that ::after is technically create an element as the last child of the element the pseudo selector is applied to and for ::before is first child. Firefox doesn't like to create children inside of its check boxes.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - for some reason it never occurred to me that the problem was simply that `<input>`s don't have children! That gives me another idea to solve it, just using a div instead of a checkbox. I'm going to have to go to bed in a minute, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, I've now solved this to my satisfaction, and while it's not exactly this way, it's not hugely different, and your answer, and the subsequent discussion, are definitely what led me to my solution - so I've decided to accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to record it in brief, what I ended up doing was putting a `<div>` as the next sibling of the checkbox, hiding the checkbox with `opacity: 0;`, and positioning the div on top of the checkbox but with lower z-index. This means that the "fake" checkbox responds in the same way a real one would, and by keeping the actual checkbox in the DOM hopefully this would still score reasonably on accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the appearance:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    /* Reset */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

But the best way is here: https://moderncss.dev/pure-css-custom-checkbox-style/

Example snippet:

```css
/* Checkboxes */
input[type=checkbox] {
    /* Reset */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #23151d;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:disabled::before,
input[type=checkbox]:disabled::after {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked::before {
    border: 1px solid #e63244;
    background: transparent;
    background: #e6324403;
}
input[type=checkbox]::after {
    content: '✓';
    text-indent: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    display: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
    display: block;
    color: #e63244;
}
/* / Checkboxes */
```

```html
<p>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled>
<input type="checkbox" disabled>
</p>
```