# how to make custom checkboxes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make custom checkboxes for different colors (red, blue, etc...)

[image]

but I'm having issues figuring out how to get the desired result

I'm using Bootstrap 5.3:
trying to learn how to do it by deconstructing a bootstrap template that has the desired result. here's the example (shop leftsidebar => filter-options):
https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=35287
First I made the standard checkbox invisible by adding the code below into my scss (connected to the Bootstrap class).

```css
.form-check-input{
  border: 0;
  background: none;
}
```

as for the color balls this is the code I have that's sort of based on the site I mentioned

```html
<div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label class="checkbox-ring-size rounded-circle border border-1 border-danger">
                        <span class="checkbox-color-size rounded-circle bg-danger">

                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check-label font-philos-ita" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        RED
                    </label>
                </div>
```

these 2 are custom classes in here
checkbox-ring-size and checkbox-color-size
the idea is one is the outer line, meaning selected

```css
.checkbox-ring-size{
  width:14px;
  height:14px;
}
```

and the other is just the color bal.

```css
.checkbox-color-size{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

I'm currently at a loss at this point. I have no idea how to make this custom checkbox clickable, indicating that its being selected.
maybe something that I should mention is that even though the standard bootstrap checkbox is invisible, if you click on the area it is in, it will still be checkable. so I also need to find a way to solve that issue
though the bootstrap template also suffers from this, but its custom buttons work.

I would appreciate the help, preferably keep using Bootstrap as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that completely without labels, by directly styling the checkbox itself. By setting [`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) to `none`, and using the `:checked`, `::before` and `::after` pseudo selectors.

```css
:root {
  --checkbox-radius: 20px;
  --checkbox-ring-distance: 2px;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: var(--checkbox-radius);
  height: var(--checkbox-radius);
  border-radius: var(--checkbox-radius);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  content: '';
  width: calc(var(--checkbox-radius) + var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*2 );
  height: calc(var(--checkbox-radius) + var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*2 );
  border-radius:  calc(var(--checkbox-radius) + var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*2 );
  left: calc(var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*-1);
  top:  calc(var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*-1);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="thecheckbox">
<label for="thecheckbox">checkbox</label>
```

If you really want to do it with a `label` you would use the next-sibling combinator:

```css
:root {
  --checkbox-radius: 20px;
  --checkbox-ring-distance: 2px;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label span {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: var(--checkbox-radius);
  height: var(--checkbox-radius);
  border-radius: var(--checkbox-radius);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span::after {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  content: '';
  width: calc(var(--checkbox-radius) + var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*2 );
  height: calc(var(--checkbox-radius) + var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*2 );
  border-radius:  calc(var(--checkbox-radius) + var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*2 );
  left: calc(var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*-1);
  top:  calc(var(--checkbox-ring-distance)*-1);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="thecheckbox">
<label for="thecheckbox"><span></span></label>
<label for="thecheckbox">checkbox</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a second element, within a parent element, that uses `::after` with the checkbox's `:checked` property. Here's some modified code from one of my own projects that I edited a bit to work for your question:

```css
.checkarea input {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.customcheck {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
  border-radius: 30%;
}
.checkarea input:checked ~ .customcheck {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
.customcheck:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.checkarea input:checked ~ .customcheck:after {
  display: block;
}
.checkarea .customcheck:after {
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 9px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="checkarea">
  <input type="checkbox" style="opacity: 0;">
  <span class="customcheck"></span>
</label>
```

**NOTE:** Using `::before` or `::after` on the checkbox itself won't work well, [since it is self closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633229/to-what-self-closing-elements-can-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-be-applie).